# Segmentation fault (core dumped) in yasm

Tags: assembly, yasm

I am kind of starting new in assembly programming. I wrote the code you see down, which is meant to be bubblesort in assembly. But when I compile it with yams I got the error "Segmentation fault (core dumped)".  By the way I am running my program with

```
yams -f elf -p gas bubble sort.asm
```

on a ubuntu system. 
Thanks first of all for all you're help, I did rewrite my program. But I still got the same error. I now know, thanks to gdb, that it is a stack overflow from the array. But I don´t know how to fix it.
If I comment out the 2 lines below, it is working fine:

```
movl (,%edi,4),%eax
movl 4(%edi,%esi,4),%ebx
```

Now here is the rest all together.

```
.data
a:  .long   16,5,18,12,11,66,62,1,9,33
ausgabe: .string "Wert %d\n"
    .text
    .globl  main

main :
    leal a, %edi
    movl $0, %edx # j= 0
    movl $10, %ecx # n =10
    decl %ecx # i = n-1
    movl $0, %eax

.L1:
    cmpl %ecx, %edx # j < i
    jge .L3 
    movl (,%edi,4),%eax
    movl 4(%edi,%esi,4),%ebx
    movl %eax, %edi
    #incl %edi
    cmpl %ebx, %eax #a[j] > a[j+1]
    jge .L2  
    #movl %eax, %esp #temp = a[j]
    #movl %ebx, %eax #a[j] = a[j+1]
    #movl %esp, %ebx #a[j+1] = temp
    xchg %ebx, %eax
.L2:
.L3:
    incl %edx #j++

   loop .L1

    pushl a(,%eax,4)
    pushl $ausgabe
    call printf

.done:

#exit
movl $1, %eax
int $0x80
```

Comment: **Format your code**.

Comment: I'm not so sure about the order `.text`, `.data`, stuff that should be in the data segment (`a`), stuff that should be in the text segment (all your executable code). Also, have you tried to use a debugger to step through the program?

Comment: You can't be using `yams -f elf -p gas bubble sort.asm` to compile since it should be `yasm` not `yams`. As well you seem to be compiling a file with a space in it `bubble sort.asm` should be `bubble\ sort.asm` (note the backslash that is escaping the space. The alternative is to put quotes around the file name with a space like `"bubble sort.asm"` . So your command line could be `yasm -f elf -p gas bubble\ sort.asm` or `yasm -f elf -p gas "bubble sort.asm"`

Comment: The command line you are using (if it assembled) doesn't actually create an executable. It creates an object (in this case an ELF object). Since you call `printf` you must be using `gcc` to create the final executable. Can you put both the yasm and the gcc command you are using into your question. Since yoy can generate code for x86 and x64 I would recommend specifying that when you use yasm and gcc. Something like `yasm -f elf32 -p gas bubble\ sort.asm` and `gcc -m32 bubble\ sort.o -o bubble\ sort` would produce a 32 bit executable called `bubble sort`

Comment: I notice you commented out the lines  `#pushl  %ebp` `#movl   %edx, %ebp` but at the end of your main function you do `leave`. `leave` requires the stackframe to be set up at the beginning of the function.  There is a bug in the commented lines.It should be `pushl  %ebp` `movl   %esp, %ebp` (_DX_ should be %esp) . I'd uncomment those lines, make the fix I suggest and keep the `leave` at the end

Comment: `.text` needs to be just below all your variables and just before the code to `main` . `.LC0:` is a variable, that needs to be in your `data` section.

Comment: It seems to me based on the output that you took a _C_ program and dumped it out as assembler and then hacked some stuff in?

Comment: `movl a, %edx`  moves the value at address a and moves it into `%edx`. Unless I'm mistaken you really want to be moving the address of `a` into `%edx`. You need to put a `$` in front of `a` to get the address so `movl $a, %edx` would be correct IMHO

Comment: In 32-bit code on Linux in order to use `printf` you have to push your parameters on the stack (from right to left). You don't seem to be doing that. You also need to add the number of bytes pushed on the stack to %esp right after you do the `call printf`

Comment: After you do `pushl %ebp` `movl %esp, %ebp` at the top of your code (per my suggestion) you should be aligning the stack. I recommend on a 16 byte boundary so I'd use  `andl  $-16, %esp`

Comment: This question is not useful to other people.